# Using UNION operator in editionable views

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

We are using Oracle database 11g and we created a query using Unions to fetch certain records.When My team mate ran the query on an editionable view we realized that editionable views do no support UNION operator.

I did some research on editionable views and understood that edition based redefinition allows multiple versions of plsql objects, views and synonyms in a single schema, which makes it possible to perform upgrades of databse applications with zero downtime.

Can someone throw some more light on editionable views and are there any alternatives to using Union or what is the impact to change to non editionable view?

Answer (score 1):

From oracle docs:

> An editioning view is a single-table view that selects all rows from
>   the base table and displays a subset of the base table columns. You
>   can use an editioning view to isolate an application from DDL changes
>   to the base table during administrative operations such as upgrades

so you do not need your "UNION" view to be editionable, in case of structure changes in underlying tables just use editioning view on that tables.